# RichFaces GUI displayed as text

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces, facelets, glassfish-3

I am running a simple RichFaces example. Mainly using Tabs. The example is shown on
JBoss website found at:

http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=tabPanel&skin=blueSky

Running the code results in the following page:

```
Overview    
«
↓
»

RichFaces is a component library for JSF and an advanced framework for easily integrating 

AJAX capabilities into business applications.

100+ AJAX enabled components in two libraries
```

...

Notice the overview should be a clickable tab. Instead I get

Overview
«
↓
»

There is no error messages from the GlassFish server. I am using Netbeans with Facelets, RichFaces 4.0 and JSF 2.0.

My web.xml is

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
        <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
        <param-value>enable</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/richexample.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Library:

```
richfaces-components-api-4.0.0.Final.jar
richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.Final.jar
richfaces-core-api-4.0.0.Final.jar
richfaces-core-impl-4.0.0.Final.jar
sac-1.3.jar
guava-10.0.1.jar
cssparser-0.9.5.jar
GlassFish 3.x (libraries)
```

Appreciate any hint or feedback as I do not have a clue why graphics are not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

What URL did you use to access your page? In your web.xml you mapped `Faces Servlet` to the `/faces` prefix, so your URL must include this (even though your actual page is not really on that path).

You can add additional mappings in your web.xml, like the common *.jsf or *.xhtml or replace the existing one, e.g.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>       
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: The URL is ok. Part of the page is loaded and you can navigate from page to page. RichFaces components do not get displayed graphically. This is the only issue.

Comment: If you look at the HTML source code in your browser, do you see the richfaces server side markup then? e.g. rich:dataTable etc?